# SQL Subtract Time from a DateTime

Tags: sql

I have two fields of data, 'CreatedDate' datetime (eg. 2013-11-06 1:00:00.000) and another is 'TimeToLive' time(7) (eg. 01:00:00)

I would like to check if the created date is more than an hour past the current time

I have tried 
DATEADD(hour, - (TimeToLive), GETDATE()); and various implementation doing a convert to datetime to get the adjusted datetime but no success overall

Comment: which database(I am guessing sql-server) and version. Could you include some examples and expected results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, -DATEPART(hour, TimeToLive), GETDATE());
```

If needed you can expand to subtract other date parts as well (minutes, seconds).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you might want to check out the NUMTODSINTERVAL functionality.